# How to find the points of tangency of a parabola using Calculus?

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

How can someone find the points of tangency of a parabola in this situation?

I need to find two points of tangency so that the triangle formed by the two tangent lines at those points and the x axis is an equilateral triangle.

What approach should I take?

I know that I can find the slope of a tangent line passing through the point (x,y) by just taking the derivative of that function and by using the point-slope formula I can get the equation of that tangent line. However, I would need to know the point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** In order to form an equilateral triangle with the $x$ axis, one of the tangents must slope upwards by 60° and the other must slope downwards by 60°. But as long as they do this (and don't happen to have the same $x$ intercept) they will form an equilateral triangle somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't figure out an approach by which I can calculate the points...

All I know is that I can get the equation of the tangent lines by using the derivative (which is the slope), but I need to know the points... this is kind of the opposite process...

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta: You need to find the $x$ such that $f'(x)=\tan 60^\circ$. If you insert the expression for the derivative, what does that look like?

Comment: (-(√3/2), 1/4), ((√3/2), 1/4)